Integrate self-hosted gitlab with AWS to connect repo in AWS Amplify
AWS opens poppup with gitlab.com instead of my self-hosted gitlab. Even when i have available connection in aws with gitlab
When i was trying to create a new app in AWS Amplify, while connecting with Gitlab it opens the poppup of the default gitlab.com/. After, I was trying to create connection with gitlab and i have created this custom url like gitlab.example.company/ but it didnt help me, anyway opens gitlab.com login poppup.
There is a way connect via codecommit, but new rules wont me do this.
Do you know any ways how to integrate self-hosted gitlab with AWS to connect repo in AWS Amplify?

Are you still looking for an answer?

yea............
